# Apple store rejection due to App Icon

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, screenshot

I have submitted an update for my already approved app on Apple store yesterday. It got rejected with this message

> "Your app icon and screenshots include content which is too similar to
>   iPad and iPhone, which creates a misleading association with Apple
>   products."

The app is available on `iPhone` as well as `iPad`. I did not get this issue when I submitted the app the first time as well as 5 updates after that. I can change the screenshots but do I need to have seprate App icons for `iPhone` and `iPad`?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What apple is trying to say is that your icon design is such that they look very similar to that of apple products and users might confuse them with apple apps. Reviewers are humans and sometimes you get a strict reviewer and hence your app is rejected this time even if it was approved earlier

Comment: could you attach the app icon that was rejected... it might help others to get going in the right direction with their own apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as apple says:

*Every app must supply both small and large app icons. The small icons are used on the Home screen and throughout the system once your app is installed. The large icon is used by the App Store.*

You can read more about it here:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have small and large icons. As I mentioned I am just submitting an update for the app which is already approved about 3 months ago. I havn't changed any App Icon in this update. Is it that  I need to have two different Icons for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: My App icon contains of an iPad an iPhone symbol. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @helloworld: Yes that is the reason

Comment: Yes, the part where they mention that "it contains a misleading association with apple products" . You might want to read this similar problem where the app was rejected because of the screenshot contained home screen and native app icons:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177192/how-to-react-on-appstore-rejection-of-screenshots

Comment: Thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

They are complaining that your icons look too much like Apple's own icons. Make entirely new ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned I am just submitting an update for the app which is already approved about 3 months ago. I havn't changed any App Icon in this update.

Comment: My App icon contains of an iPad an iPhone symbol. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Absolutely. — The fact that this got past them before is unimportant. They have noticed it now. That is all that matters.